# Testing functions which have inner functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function that returns a boolean based on values that are passed in an inner function. That main parent function takes in values which is then compared with the values passed in the inner function.

```
function withinMiles(miles, max) {
  return (customer) =>
    calculateMiles(
      customer.distance,
      miles.distance,
    ) <= max;
}
```

I tried to test the function like below

```
test("Customer is within 500 miles", () => {
  expect(withinMiles(250, 500)).toBe(true);
});
```

However, I get the following error

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: [Function anonymous]

   8 | 
   9 | test("Users are within 500Miles", () => {
> 10 |   expect(withinMiles(250, 500)).toBe(true);
     |                               ^
  11 | });
  12 | 

  at Object.<anonymous> (app.test.js:10:31)
```

Comment: ... You (sort of) answered your own question--the return value of `withinMiles` is a function. You have to call that function with a `customer`y object. It's the *inner* function that returns a boolean, not `withinMiles`. The misleadingly-named `withinMiles` is a function builder.

Comment: It's not just a function that has inner function but higher-order function. This means that inner function can still be tested, while it wouldn't be true if it weren't returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withinMiles` is returning a function, and a function is obviously not equal to the boolean `true`.

There's no good way to compare functions to each other directly, so you will need to call that function with a `customer` to make the test pass:

```
expect(withinMiles(250, 500)(someCustomer)).toBe(true);
```